# Fullcalendar show dates outside of validrange

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a calendar that has a `validrange` and a `visiblerange` set like below. I want the calendar events that aren't in this range to be visible but greyed out. At the moment if the event falls outside this range it doesn't appear.

```
visibleRange: {
                start: PeriodStart,
                end: PeriodEnd
            },
            validRange: {
                start: PeriodStart,
                end: PeriodEnd
            },
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You mention the `validRange` and `visibleRange` parameters, and then refer to one of them as `this range`. Which one? Are you asking why the events outside the visibleRange are not visible?

Comment: Apologies. I have tried both of these options to see which might work for what I need with no success.

What I need is to be able to lock down a fortnight period so that nothing can be entered outside of that period, but I want the previous period to still be visible. At the moment with either of these options anything outside that 2 week period is not visible.

Comment: It is not visible because you set a `visibleRange` parameters. What is outside this range will obviously be discarded. You might want to check `selectConstraint` (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectConstraint) and `eventConstraint` (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventConstraint) which might be better suited for what you try to achieve.